# ElasticSearch: cannot find or load PluginManagerCliParser class

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been trying to install the ElasticSearch-Head plugin, using this command prompt:

```
$ ./bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

But it keeps saying this:

```
Error : cannot find or load main class org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManagerCliParser
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of elasticsearch are you using?  The install instructions for each version is shown here.

https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head

Comment: Thanks! it appears that it's `install` and not `-install` that I should use.

Answer (score 0):

I added the .bat extension and removed the "-" to install:

```
$ ./bin/plugin.bat install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```